# Dynamically loading aliases into current shell

Tags: bash, shell, alias

Haven't been able to crack this one, any help would be apprecaited.

I have a small script that does some logic and then tries to create aliases for me to load into my shell.  I've tried several different approaches to do so, but haven't been able to get anything better than this. Which feels like a nasty hack.

```
 script.pl > new_aliases.txt && source new_aliases.txt && rm new_aliases.txt
```

Ideally, this happens inside a .bashrc file so it's loaded when the shell starts.  The best I've been able to do is wrap the line above in a shell function and then calling that manually after the shell starts.

Inside my .profile

```
function load_aliases () {
    script.pl > new_aliases.txt && source new_aliases.txt && rm new_aliases.txt
}
```

Then after shell starts...

> load_aliases

Like I said this does what I want, but 1) it's damn ugly and 2) manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want

```
eval "$(script.pl)"
```

If you want this in an interactive function, you should put in the full path to `script.pl` so it works regardless of which directory you are in; or, of course, have `script.pl` in your `PATH`.

If you want to put this in a function in your `.profile`, you need to make sure the output doesn't produce any Bashisms, because `.profile` is shared with other shells.  Maybe put it in `.bash_profile` instead (but note that of you create a new `.bash_profile`, this disables reading `.profile` when you start Bash, so you will want to do that explicitly from your `.bash_profile` then).

For example, `source` and `function` are (rather superfluous IMHO) Bash extensions, which are not valid commands in regular `sh`.

The usual caveats about `eval` apply, of course, but this is no more unsafe than what you are already doing.

Comment: `eval "$(script.pl)"`, ¿no?

Comment: @rici Thanks. I was hesitating about that, but you are definitely right.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the `load_aliases` command into your `.bashrc`?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `eval` solution, you can also use process substitution to treat the output of `script.pl` as a file.

```
source <(script.pl)
```

This should work, although I can't shake the nagging suspicion that I ran into an issue once with `source` expecting a real file, not what is essentially a pipe.